# How to throw an error on a Firebase callable cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a new user on Firebase using a callable cloud function. Whenever there is an error (eg: the email is invalid) the function always returns the same cryptic error to my Firebase app no matter what I do:

```
{"error":{"status":"INTERNAL","message":"INTERNAL"}}
```

In the Firebase console I also get this:

```
Unhandled error Error: Unknown error status: auth/invalid-email
```

Which doesn't make much sense since I am actually handling the error. This is the code of the cloud function:

```
exports.createUser = (data, context) => {
    return admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password
    }).catch((error) => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error.errorInfo.code, error.errorInfo.message);
    });
}
```

As shown I've tried to use `throw functions.https.HttpsError` which is what the [documentation suggests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors).

I've also tried `return functions.https.HttpsError` or even throwing my own error with the same result.

I've used try/catch with `await` instead of using `then()` and `catch()`. Same result. The functions console still informs me that the error is not handled which is absurd.

So how can I throw a proper error to my users when using a callable cloud function?

Comment: That doesn't look like the proper definition of a Cloud Function that uses the Firebase CLI for deployment.  According to the same documentation that you linked, you should have an export that looks like this: `exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall()`

Comment: This is just the function. This is how it's exported `exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(createUser);`. It works for creating users.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to pass along the error code from the Admin SDK verbatim, but that's not a valid strategy.  Read the documentation carefully - it's sending you to the [API documentation for HttpsError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror) to find the list of error codes that are valid to send.  The [code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror.html#code) property links to [FunctionsErrorCode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.html#functionserrorcode) which shows the list of valid codes:

> "ok" | "cancelled" | "unknown" | "invalid-argument" | "deadline-exceeded" | "not-found" | "already-exists" | "permission-denied" | "resource-exhausted" | "failed-precondition" | "aborted" | "out-of-range" | "unimplemented" | "internal" | "unavailable" | "data-loss" | "unauthenticated"

The Admin SDK is giving you "auth/invalid-email", which is not valid here.  You're going to have to translate that into one of the valid codes.  Perhaps "invalid-argument" might be appropriate.  That's going to get translated further into a numerical HTTP response code, which you will receive on the client.

Comment: Thanks, yes this was it. It's pretty amazing that the console or the error returned to the client does not mention any of this.

Comment: That's kinda what the error message "Unknown error status" is suggesting.  But it could be more clear, and that's reasonable to as in a feature request in the project GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions

Comment: Apparently they don't want feature requests via Github and are asking to do it here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Since the links above are 404s, check out the following link:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https#functionserrorcode
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

Answer (score 1):

To throw an error to the client that called your Firebase Cloud Function, the function must throw a specific `HttpsError` error and the error's code, which is the error's first argument, must be a Firebase-compliant string identifier. The Firebase-compliant string identifiers, such as `invalid-argument` and `already-exists`, can be found in the API reference.

```
exports.test = functions.https.onCall(async (_data, _context) => {
    try {
        // something that throws...
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", error);
    }
});
```

However, I don't find the mandatory string identifiers particularly useful because I've had to throw errors back to the client that didn't fit under any of them. Therefore, I prefer to use the "unknown" identifier, which is on the approved list, and construct my own errors for the client to parse.

```
exports.test = functions.https.onCall(async (_data, _context) => {
    try {
        // something that throws...
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "custom-identifier", error);
    }
});
```

Be careful not to overload the thrown error with arguments because the limit is three. The first argument is the code, the second argument is the message, and the third argument is the details. On many clients, the second argument is treated as the error's localized description and the third is treated as its details.